# The word order of the separable verb "nachkommen"

Tags: word-order

> Zum Glück **kommt** Felix **nach** seinem Vater.

How does it compare to saying:

> Zum Glück **kommt** Felix seinem Vater **nach**.
>
> {or}: Zum Glück **kommt** seinem Vater Felix **nach**.

I usually see a separable prefix "nach/aus/ab/etc" placed at the end, but in this example, "nach" is followed by the dative case "seinem Vater".

I wonder how this word order compares to when "nach" is placed at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nachkommen** is a tricky verb:

> Zum Glück kommt Felix seinem Vater nach.

Fortunately Felix obeys his father.

> Zum Glück kommt Felix nach seinem Vater.

Fortunately Felix is like his father.

---

**Nachschauen** is similar:

> Zum Glück schaute Felix nach seinem Vater.

Fortunately Felix watched over his father.

> Zum Glück schaute Felix seinem Vater nach.

Fortunately Felix watched his father leaving.

Comment: Hi. I wonder if the same goes for: "ich komme nach Ihnen = I'm after you" vs "ich komme Ihnen nach = I agree with you"?

Comment: Yes. But *Ich komme ihnen nach* would usually be understand as *I obey **them***, with "them" being rules or wishes someone had.

Comment: Oh, I see. Beim Objekt des Verbs "nachkommen" handelt es sich nicht um Personen, sondern um Sachen.

Comment: Ja, meistens ist das so. Wenn es eine Person ist, heißt das, dass man den Wünschen oder Anweisungen dieser Person nachkommt.

Comment: Im Satz »Felix kommt nach seinem Vater« kommt das Verb »nachkommen« gar nicht vor. Oder irre ich mich da?

Comment: Das ist Ansichtssache. Guck in ein Wörterbuch, da ist unter *nachkommen* die Bedeutung *jemandem ähneln* häufig aufgeführt.

Comment: This answer is not correct. _jmdm. nachkommen_ is not _nach jmdm. kommen_ and _jmdm. nachschauen_ is not _nach jmdm. schauen_. Nachkommen and nachschauen are each one verb. In the other cases kommen and schauen are used with a preposition and have another meaning. So they are actually different words with different meanings.

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachkommen

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachschauen

Comment: @Janka, es ist ja schön, dass du hier auf die Bedeutung des _einen_ Verbs, nämlich _nachkommen_ verweist. Nun hättest du eigentlich noch auf Bedeutung 16 des _anderen_ Verbs, nämlich _kommen_, verweisen müssen (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kommen#Bedeutung16a). Aber zumindest sollte jetzt klar sein, dass es _zwei verschiedene_ Verben sind.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich, ich habe die beiden Dudenseiten extra deshalb verlinkt, weil dort jeweils *beide* Bedeutungen für *nachkommen* gelistet sind. (Und für *nachschauen* ebenso). Wie ich das oben ja auch schrieb. Ich kann nichts dafür, dass du das anders siehst.

Comment: Dass beide Bedeutungen bei _nachkommen_ gelistet sind, bedeutet wohl vor allem, dass "Felix kommt seinem Vater nach" beide Bedeutungen haben kann, nicht dass "nach X kommen" und "X nachkommen" beide das Verb "nachkommen" enthalten. Wenn ich mich im Stockbett über meinen Bruder lege, überlege ich deshalb ja auch nicht.

Answer (score 7):

What you see here is a problem in the German language:

> Felix **kommt** **nach** mir.

The verb here is not "*nachkommen*" but "*kommen*". The word "*nach*" is a separate word in this sentence which does not belong to the verb at all.

> Felix **kommt** mir **nach**.

In this sentence the verb really is "*nachkommen*".

The same is true for the word "*nachsehen*" (or "*nachschauen*") in the Janka's answer.

-- **Edit** --

Let's convert the examples from Janka's answer to future tense:

> Zum Glück wird Felix **nach** seinem Vater **schauen**.
>
> Zum Glück wird Felix seinem Vater **nachschauen**.

In future tense you can see that in one case the verb is the separable verb "*nachschauen*" and in the other case the verb is "*schauen*" and "*nach*" is a separate word.

Comment: Hi. So in "Felix kommt **nach** mir", the "nach" is a preposition, correct?

Comment: The problem is dictionaries tend to list both meanings for *nachkommen*, and not for *kommen*.

Comment: @Janka, they do not: https://www.dwds.de/wb/nachkommen versus https://www.dwds.de/wb/kommen (interpretation 10)

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/nachkommen, Bedeutung1 vs. Bedeutung 4.

Comment: @Janka This would not influence the answer original question: When using "Bedeutung 4" of "*nachkommen*" the word order would be: "*Felix **kommt** mir **nach**.*". You see that in the example at duden.de. The word order of "*kommt*" and "*nach*" is always the same if the verb "*nachkommen*" is used. According to duden.de the verbs "*jmd. nachkommen*" and "*nach jmd. kommen*" (actually: "*kommen*") can be used as synonyms here.